# Filtering out any records which do not parse correctly using Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a txt file that contains several lines. See examples of 2 lines below:

```
2014-03-15:10:10:20,Sorrento F41L,8cc3b47e-bd01-4482-b500-28f2342679af,7,24,39,enabled,disabled,connected,55,67,12,33.6894754264,-117.543308253
2014-03-15:10:10:20|MeeToo 1.0|ef8c7564-0a1a-4650-a655-c8bbd5f8f943|0|31|63|70|39|27|enabled|enabled|enabled|37.4321088904|-121.485029632
```

As you can see, the first line is comma delimited while the second line is pipe delimited. The file contains a lot of lines, some of them are comma delimited and some others are pipe delimited.

What I need to do is to filter out any records which do not parse correctly (i.e. Each correctly parsed record/line should have exactly 14 values/fields)

First I read the file using sc.textFile("/path/filename.txt"), but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Are both pipe and comma separated lines value? Can commas appear in pipe separated lines, and pipes in comma separated lines? Basically you need to define what you mean by "parse correctly".

Comment: No, commas will not appear in pipe separated lines and also pipes will not appear in comma separated lines.

Comment: So you can just split on `[|,]`, and then count the fields as in @stevewaldram's answer.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I already did. So thanks a lot, it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
sc.textFile("/path/filename.txt").map( _.split("[|,]") ).filter( _.length == 14 )
```